# Add-AzTableRow command is not available in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to insert new row in my table storage by using Azure Cloud Shell but I'm facing below exception. So let me know any other command that we need to use to insert.

> Blockquote

```
 Add-AzTableRow: The term 'Add-AzTableRow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

> Blockquote

**Below are the command:**

```
$partitionKey1 = "partition1"
$partitionKey2 = "partition2"


Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"="Chris";"userid"=1}
```

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the error, it seems that you do not install the module [`AzTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.0.2). Please run the command `Get-InstalledModule` to check if you have installed the module.
[image]

If you have not installed the module, please run the command `Install-Module -Name AzTable -Force` to install it.

For example

```
Install-Module -Name AzTable -Force
Import-Module AzTable
$resourceGroup = "<your group name>"
$storageAccountName ="<your account name>"
$storageAccount=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$tableName = "<table name>"
$cloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx).CloudTable

$partitionKey1 = "partition1"
Add-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -partitionKey $partitionKey1 -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"="Chris";"userid"=1}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim for exact solution, I forget to execute this command "Install-Module -Name AzTable -Force".

Comment: Is the `-force` parameter essential?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger You can do not use it. Without it, powershell  will ask you whether to install the module. with it, powershell will directly install the module.